# When is the memory allocated for local variables in functions?

Tags: java

I know that memory allocated for functions and `static` members is done only once, and that class variables are given new memory space each time a new object is created.

Once I use the `new` operator in this following problem, I will get 8 bytes for the class variables.  But, when is memory for `int c` allocated?  During compile time?

```
class A
{
    int a,b;

    void show()
    {
        int c;
    }

    public static void main(String...s)
    {
        new A().show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Local varialbe is locally allocated on stack.

Comment: can u help me with a link ?

Comment: More than you ever wanted to know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap

Comment: well, what I think you really need is, something about programming, not java memory mgmt blahblah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method calls and local variables are stored on stack. Objects (containing instance variables) are stored on heap. So the object created using:

```
new A()
```

will be stored on heap and `show` method local variable `c` will be created stored on stack when you call the method.

Just check this image to understand more about stack and heap memory management in Java:

[image]

Comment: helpful... :D
now pls expalin this-
once first() is put onto stack , ( this happens during compile time right?). then memory is allocated to it.and if we again call first , then fresh memory will be allocated to first() or is this just a function call to a fixed memory location elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The memory for a function's local variables is allocated each time the function is called, on the stack.

Comment: so each time new memory is allocated to local vars? i thought that memory was allocated only once to functions and their vars!

Comment: with a quick look, this page looks promising: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: man exams are starting from monday and all these enticing topics i'm unearthing right now !

Comment: so memory is allocated for local variables on the stack every time.but for static functions and variables , there ought to be a fixed space ryt?

Comment: static functions work the same as normal functions, except that they operate on the Class instead of an instance - meaning the members referenced can only be static members, not instance members (since there is no instance known at static-method-call-time).  Static variables are allocated one time - when the class is loaded, that's right.

Comment: to clarify - local variables in static functions are allocated on the stack just like other functions.  And static functions can be recursive.